# listings comment style not applied on language operators

Tags: listings

I'm using the `listings` package to typeset some Haskell and Scala code in my document,
and I've defined a simple style named `ttt`. I set comments to be displayed in red for contrast, but the problem remains even for simpler styles that don't involve colors.

Whether I use Scala or Haskell in the `lstlistings` environment does not matter. I get the same problem anyway, which is that if a comment contains specific operators of the corresponding language, then the comment style does not apply to them. For (a kinda minimal) example, suppose I want to comment whole lines of code, as below (nonsensical code, for illustration).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstloadlanguages{Scala, Haskell}
\lstdefinestyle{ttt}
               {basicstyle=\ttfamily,
               columns=flexible,
               commentstyle=\color{red},
               frame=single}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=ttt, language=Scala, caption=Scala]
      // def addone : Int => Int = x => x + 1
      val z = 1       // def f[a](x:a) : a = g[a](x)
      // val v2 = g[Int](z)
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[style=ttt, language=Haskell, caption=Haskell]
    -- addone :: Eq a => a -> Bool
    -- addone x = x + 1
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The above is typeset like this:

[image: result]

The `=` and `=>` symbols are special operators in Haskell and Scala.

What I expect (and want to achieve) is that in Listing 1, lines 1 and 3 should be entirely red and in line 2 everything should be red after the `//` comment delimiter.
Similarly, in Listing 2, line 1 should also be entirely red.

Have I hit a bug? Is there a solution?

Comment: As always on the site you are much more likely to get any help if you provide small complete self contained examples instead of sniplets like this. The small examples can be copied and testes as is. Here for sniplets we have to add document class, preamble etc.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the advice! I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that `=>` and `=` are defined as `otherkeyword` in the Scala and Haskell definitions, and these are processed even when the keyword is in comments. This seems to be a bug.

As a workaround you can use the system of hooks that `listings` provides. There are a number of hooks to execute code in specific circumstances. A list can be found in the [Developer's Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings-devel.pdf) on page 69. One of the hooks is `AfterBeginComment` which is executed at the start of a comment. You can use this hook to set the text color to red. This seems redundant if the comment color is already red, but the color specification in this hook sets the general color (as opposed to the comment color specifically). The color is reset automatically at the end of a comment.

The command to set the hook `\lst@AddToHook` contains an `@` sign, therefore the call must be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstloadlanguages{Scala, Haskell}
\lstdefinestyle{ttt}
               {basicstyle=\ttfamily,
               columns=flexible,
               commentstyle=\color{red},
               frame=single}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{AfterBeginComment}{\color{red}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=ttt, language=Scala, caption=Scala]
      // def addone : Int => Int = x => x + 1
      val z = 1       // def f[a](x:a) : a = g[a](x)
      // val v2 = g[Int](z)
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[style=ttt, language=Haskell, caption=Haskell]
    -- addone :: Eq a => a -> Bool
    -- addone x = x + 1
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With my little knowledge I've found a patchy solution that requires modifying the code written within the `lstlisting` environments. This solution uses the `literate` option of the package.
It would be nice to see a cleaner solution, though, that does not require modifications in the code. The behaviour I describe in the question still feels like a bug.

Instead of using the problematic `=` and `=>` symbols in the comments, I use `c=c` and `c=>c`, respectively, and then use `literate` to translate them to their normal counterparts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstloadlanguages{Scala, Haskell}
\lstdefinestyle{ttt}
               {basicstyle=\ttfamily,
               %columns=flexible,
               commentstyle=\color{red},
               frame=single,
               literate={c=c}{=}1 {c=>c}{=>}2}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[style=ttt, language=Scala, caption=Scala]
      // def addone : Int => Int c=c x c=>c x + 1
      val z = 1       // def f[a](x:a) : a c=c g[a](x)
      // val v2 = g[Int](z)
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[style=ttt, language=Haskell, caption=Haskell]
    -- addone :: Eq a c=>c a -> Bool
    -- addone x = x + 1
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, if `columns=flexible` is specified, spacing will be incorrect in the printed code, but patchy adjustments in the `literate` entries can recover from that:

```
literate={c=c}{= }2 {c=>c}{=> }3
```

The above latex code with `columns=flexible` not-commented and with the adapted `literate` option, gives the following:

[image]